# Report showing NO DATA when uploaded to crm online

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

When building a report in SSRS and viewing it in PREVIEW mode, my report is showing lots of data; however, when deploying it to CRM online 2013, this is what I am getting:

[image]

1. This is CRM DYNAMICS ONLINE 2013
2. The data source is FetchXML and does not change
3. I've removed all filters from the report and it still displays nothing.
4. I'm using windows authentication

My FetchXML data source is configured this way:
[image]

**Why is my report being generated fine in preview mode, yet when I upload it to CRM 2013 online, it displays no data?**

Comment: From your first image, it appears you still have some filters on the Opportunity. Have you clickd "Edit Filter" from the report in CRM and cleared out those filters?

Comment: Hi Yuck, are the permissions you run the report under different from your dev and from the actual report?

Comment: Also not sure about it, but is the online org already 2015? I noticed that all the sdk dlls needs to be the ones from the new sdk. Maybe the connector, if you are not using the latest one, has problems with it.

Comment: Usually when stuff like that happens I remove all the filters and print another table with the plain data. Also are you using what kind of parameter? The alias for the pre-filters need to be accurate as the name of the entity you are querying too. The pre filtering is tricky most of the time you will need a little bit of tuning to use the correct fetch. I reckon that for the dev environment the dataset comes directly in, while with the pre-filters the approach is slight different. The enableprefiltering="true" should allow you to select the correct entity to filter

Comment: @Draiden please post your answer and I will mark it correct!

Comment: I guess something went wrong when you uploaded the report. Any more info then that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered that the report wasn't querying the correct organization.

The user was admin of 4 different online orgs, and while connecting, instead of specify the unique org name we left the parameter empty, that made the report point to the default prod org.

Everything looked like was working correctly and the visual studio was showing data.

The report was then deployed on the dev org, that didn't contain any data used by the report.

To fix the problem and make the report worked as intended is necessary to add in the connection string the correct org unique name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is your [credible and/or official sources](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531151(v=crm.6).aspx):

> Connection String: Specify the connection string. The connection string must be specified in the following format:
>
> ServerURL;OrganizationName;HomeRealmURL
>
> In this connection string, only ServerURL is mandatory. If OrganizationName is not specified, the first organization that the user running this query belongs to is used. If HomeRealmURL is not specified, the value is retrieved from the registry value "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRMBidsExtensions\HomeRealmUrl".
>
> Click Credentials to specify the credentials to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM or Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online, and click Next.