# Dynamic CRM 2015 SSRS connection error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, ssrs-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

Guys.
I have an error when I tried to connect CRM 2015 online instance from VS2012. I have already installed Data Tool for VS2012 and CRM extension. Then when I create a new report wizard data source at VS2012, I choose MS Dynamic CRM Fetch as Type source. Connection string is: https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com; organization unique name; (I tried both with ";" and without ";" at the end of connection string). Set Credentials to "Use this user name and password" with my office 365 username and password.

Then I click Next, it says "Unable to connect to data source 'DataSource1'.The connection to server "https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc" could not be established. Make sure that the connection string and credentials are correct, and try again."

Then I tried, shared datasets, create a new dataset, copy and past xml file from CRM instance advance search then click "Query Desiner", it is the same error.

I am sure this server is unblocked my CRM API, I can connect CRM 2015 online using registration tool.

Anyone can give me some advice? or what should I check in my settings or configurations? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in what region is your crm instance? If you point to the wrong crm you can have trouble connecting, also in case of multiple organizations you need to specify the proper organization unique name.

check this post: [Report showing NO DATA when uploaded to crm online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931841/report-showing-no-data-when-uploaded-to-crm-online/27955570#27955570)

crm is standard for america orgs.

Comment: In North America region. I added organization unique name after instance url. And I saw your link, I did have organization unique name. Any other suggestion?